Are cross-chain Decentralized Exchanges and cross-chain bridges are the same?
I am newbie at DeFi. I am struggling with understanding what does author of Yellow paper of LayerZero mean in this sentence:
"Currently, to convert between tokens of two chains, a user must leverage either a centralized exchange or a cross-chain decentralized exchange (DEX) (also known as a cross- chain bridge)"
Does he mean that cross-chain DEX are the same as cross-chain bridges OR cross-chain bridges helps to create cross-chain DEX with their functionalities?

In the sentence you provided:

Currently, to convert between tokens of two chains, a user must
leverage either a centralized exchange or a cross-chain decentralized
exchange (DEX) (also known as a cross- chain bridge)

The author is explaining the current methods for converting tokens between two different blockchain networks.
They mention two options:

Centralized exchanges.

Cross-chain Decentralized exchanges (DEX), which are also referred to as cross-chain bridges.


The author is not saying that cross-chain DEX and cross-chain bridges are the same thing. Instead, they are stating that cross-chain DEX, or decentralized exchanges that facilitate token swaps across different blockchains, are sometimes referred to as cross-chain bridges because they serve a similar purpose of bridging different chains.
So, in this context, "cross-chain DEX (also known as a cross-chain bridge)" means that they are sometimes called cross-chain bridges due to their function of facilitating token transfers between different blockchains.


cross-chain bridges helps to create cross-chain DEX with their
functionalities?

The author is not suggesting that cross-chain DEX and cross-chain bridges are the same. Typically cross-chain decentralized exchanges (DEX) rely on cross-chain bridges to facilitate the transfer of assets between different blockchains. Cross-chain bridges enable interoperability by allowing tokens to be securely transferred from one blockchain to another, which is essential for cross-chain DEX to operate effectively.
